# How can I make a php page inaccessible to all users?

Tags: php

I'm developing an application where I have a configuration page that has some data that must be hidden from anyone who tries to access them directly, I'm currently doing a verification, but I don't know if it really is safe, I'm using this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' && realpath(__FILE__) == realpath($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])) {
    die();
}
```

In other words, any user who tries to access the page remotely dies, is this safe or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What does _"access them directly"_ mean? And what is the alternative that should work?

Comment: This looks like an include file for PHP. Best way is to use `.htaccess` or something to limit that path. Or put this file somewhere inaccessible. These are the right ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using an include file for PHP. There are three ways you can make it inaccessible via `GET` request.

1. Use `.inc` extension and make the server not serve `.inc` files and throw Error 404.
2. Put the file in a non-accessible location, out of www and use the include path, which can include file from any path.
3. Use `.htaccess` to limit the file access, i.e., see the below one:

Contents of `.htaccess` to limit config files.

```
RewriteRule ^config/.*\.(php|rb|py)$ - [F,L,NC]
```

Comment: I thought about that too, thanks. I know it's asking a lot, but could you explain why your example is safer?

Comment: @ChrisAnswood I have done this before and I understand why you wanna do it, and having a block through `.htaccess` will make absolutely sure that the file isn't accessible other ways. Also, having it out of the `www` folder will make it totally inaccessible via web. Only way is to use it via script.

Comment: Option #2 is the safest. The alternatives can be made invalid by a corrupt Apache configuration